# MongoDB - MongooseJS - Retrieve ID from parent to set child in collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, collections, persist

I am currently working in an app which the data is persisted in MongoDB using the MongooseJS.
There is a collection: **DataRoomFolder**. The documents have the following structure:

```
{
id,
isFolder,
name,
parentId: ObjectId(parent-DataRoomFolder),
projectId,
...
}
```

For each model **Project**, there is linked different **DataRoomFolder** but by default, when it is created, it will add a schema already predefined which I already have:

```
[
  {
    label: '01-Architecture',
    items: [
      { label: 'Design', items: [] },
      { label: 'Drawings', items: [] },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: '02-Permits',
    items: [{ label: 'Building Permit', items: [] }],
  },
  {
    label: '02-Permits',
    items: [{ label: 'Building Permit', items: [] }],
  },
  {
    label: '03-Control office',
    items: [
      { label: 'Construction', items: [
           { label: 'Calculation reports', items: [] },
           { label: 'Datasheets', items: [] },
           { label: 'Drawings', items: [] },
           { label: 'Hand-over reports', items: [] },
           { label: 'Maintenance checklists', items: [] },
           { label: 'One-line diagrams', items: [] },
           { label: 'Technical notices', items: [] },
        ] },
      { label: 'Environment', items: [] },
      { label: 'Safety', items: [
           { label: 'Calculation reports', items: [] },
           { label: 'Datasheets', items: [] },
           { label: 'Drawings', items: [] },
           { label: 'Hand-over reports', items: [] },
           { label: 'Maintenance checklists', items: [] },
           { label: 'One-line diagrams', items: [] },
           { label: 'Technical notices', items: [] },
        ] },
    ],
  }
```

As you can see, there is parent-children reference.

The question: when I loop for each to create every folder, I need to create have first the parent folder saved to get the ID and parsed to the children.
I saw a workaround with [Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate) but it does not fit my needs.

How should I persist to get parent IDs and carrying on adding to the children and saving and not getting affected the performance?

Thanks!

Comment: your question is about creating new document or getting ?

Comment: populate is for getting data , its the only way to create data

Comment: @mohammadNaimi, you are right! I want to create new documents and use their IDs to set as references in the children.